# Can we selectively save celery tasks to a CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am running tasks task_A, task_B and task_C on celery. Can I save only task_A result to backend.

```
from celery import task

@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=3)
def task_A():
    # Returns some json
    result = call_A()
    return result

@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=3)
def task_B():
    # Returns some json
    result = call_B()
    return result

@task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=3)
def task_C():
    # Returns some json
    result = call_C()
    return result
```

I have set:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.db'
```

I need only task_A results to be saved in database. Currently it saves all tasks result in database

Comment: yes, you can save only Task_A result

Comment: can you share you code?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I have added the code used

Comment: You are not saving data in any of task.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool If you set CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, it will save the result automatically